# NoSQL Key/Value equivalent in NoSQL Document

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql, azure-table-storage

I've been using `Microsoft Azure Table` which is a NoSQL Key/Value database. Now I need to store data in `MongoDB` which is a Document NoSQL database.

This was previously with Azure:

```
public class StudentEntity : TableEntity
{
    public StudentEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
        : base(partitionKey, rowKey)
    {
    }
}
```

I had a `students` table, `partitionKey` was university name, and `rowKey` was student id.

But I see that MongoDB documents, have only an ID for each entity. How can I fit my azure data in mongodb?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, for Azure Table Storage, the PartitionKey and RowKey combine as the unique identification for your record. And they are indexed to create a clustered index that enables fast look-ups. While for MongoDB, each document must has the `_id` property and it would work as the identification for each document.

Per my understanding, if you switch to MongoDB and reuse the data from your table storage, I assume that you could add the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` as the fields in your MongoDB document, then add index for them to optimize the query.

For data partitioning, you could leverage [Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/sharding/) to distribute data cross multiple machines. For example, you could use [Hashed Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/hashed-sharding/) and set the `PartitionKey` field of your MongoDB document as the [shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/glossary/#term-shard-key) to partition data across your sharded cluster.